# Using predict for ancillary parameters in maximum likelihood model in Stata

Tags: stata

I wanted to know whether I can use the `predict` option for ancillary parameters (maximum likelihood ) program as follows (I estimated `lnsigma` and so `sigma` is the ancillary parameter in the model):

```
predict lnsigma, eq(lnsigma)
gen sigma=exp(lnsigma)
```

I also would like to know whether we can use above for heteroscedastic model.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds correct. I would be more explicit by typing `predict lnsigma, xb eq(lnsigma)`. This way your code will not be broken when someone later on desides to write a prediction program for your estimation program and sets the default to something different than the linear prediction.

You can also do it in one line:

```
predictnl sigma = exp(xb(#2))
```

This assumes that `lnsigma` is the second equation in your model. If it is the third equation you replace `xb(#2)` with `xb(#3)`. `predictnl` is also also an easy way of using the delta method to predict standard errors and confidence intervals for `sigma`.

I assume this is your own Stata program. If that is true, then you also have a third option: You can create your own prediction program, which Stata's `predict` command will recongnize. You can find some useful tricks on how to do that here: http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?_pred_se

Comment: Thank you. I like your second option. I will try to include the prediction subroutine in my program.